# rotate to camera - billiboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, rotation

I found a lot about how to gat the angle from my camera to the objecte. But somehow it is not working... I hope you can help me there.

I am calculating the radian with

```
GLfloat rad =  atan2f(cam.z-z, cam.x-x);
```

where x and z are my x,y Values of the Object.

And I want to rotate the modelMatrix of the Object with

```
 _test_modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(x, y, z);
 _test_lokalMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeYRotation(rad);
 _test_modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_test_modelMatrix, _test_lokalMatrix);
```

This Object should be a billboard I think it's called. A picture sitting in the world and always facing me.

Comment: "Somehow it is not working" is not remotely an adequate error description. Does the object rotate in the wrong direction or what is the problem?

Comment: it is rotating, but only, I would say 5 times slower than it should

Comment: I do not understand, where is problem. Also screenshots will be very useful.